# Python xml sub catgories

Tags: python, regex, xml, python-2.7

I have this python code. This will read an external XML and bring you what is in there but I can't get it to bring up another category, i.e if I add another XML link inside the main XML I want it to bring it and open that XML file here is the code that works only to open the links in the main XML.

```
def ExtraMenu(fanart,description):
    OPEN = OPEN_URL('http://xml link to file').replace('\n','').replace('\r','')  #Spaf
    match = re.compile('<title>(.+?)</title><link>(.+?)</link><thumbnail>(.+?)</thumbnail><fanart>(.+?)</fanart>').findall(OPEN)
    for name,url,iconimage,FanArt in match:
        addXMLMenu(name,url,13,iconimage,FanArt,description)
```

This works to open links in the one XML again I want to add a second XML link inside the main XML link and that to open when clicked in the main

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please try to format your question and try to make it a little more understable. Please add all source code required to undertstand this question, including a sample of your xml file. And please try to explain what you want to link: your xml files, you menus. How should this work?